# Most common duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have a table with articleid's and tagid's.
Every article has 1 or more tags. I want to select the articles that has the (top 3 most) same tags.

Example:

```
article 2 has tags with id 1, 3, 8, 9 and 25    
article 3 has tags with id 9, 11, 25 and 30    
article 4 has tags with id 2, 3, 8, 25, 27 and 30
```

I want to have the article that has the most tags in common with, let's say, article 2. By heart, I now see it's article 4 (with 3 same tags), but how to code that?

Comment: Please provide the mysql tables structure and what code have you tried so we can help.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id, ',') from table GROUP BY article_id HAVING count(tag_id)>3`

Comment: I can't find how to post a table in here. html and tabs don't seem to work...

Comment: Use the `code` button in the editor to format your text in code style.

Comment: @Fl1p, Did you try with my query?

Comment: @FrayneKonok Doesn't work. Would be strange, as there's no variable $articleid from where he selects the original article to compare with.

Comment: you funny, just replace with your real field. you don't share real data so I use dummy.

Comment: Hehe :-) What value do I replace with the variable? I'm just a script kiddie, trying en errorring. Thanks!

Comment: as @DanielDudas ask for table structure....

Comment: are you done? you need to update your question.

Comment: Nope, still didn't work... And I don't find a way to insert tables in here...